# bad interpreter and phpize failed

Tags: centos, pecl

Trying to install do the following on Centos 5:

```
[root@d ~]# pecl install imagick
```

I got the following output:

```
downloading imagick-3.0.1.tgz ...
Starting to download imagick-3.0.1.tgz (93,920 bytes)
.....................done: 93,920 bytes
13 source files, building
running: phpize
Configuring for:
PHP Api Version:         20041225
Zend Module Api No:      20060613
Zend Extension Api No:   220060519
/usr/bin/autoconf: /usr/bin/autom4te: /usr/bin/perl: bad interpreter: Permission denied
/usr/bin/autoconf: line 271: /usr/bin/autom4te: Success
ERROR: `phpize' failed
```

Is the bad interpreter the problem?  Is this causing phpize to fail?  Or are these two separate problems?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Permission denied` to Perl? Do you have SELinux enabled or something else funny going on? Have you done something odd such as `chmod 000 /usr/bin/perl`?